# Testing Airflow Custom Operators That Read From The Context.conf Object

Tags: python, unit-testing, airflow, airflow-2.x

## Question

How can I build a unit test such that a custom operators `context` object has a correctly built `conf` object?

## Context

I have a pretty simple operator

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_create_job_flow_operator import (
    EmrCreateJobFlowOperator)

class EmrCreateOrUseJobFlowOperator(EmrCreateJobFlowOperator):
    """
    An extension of the EmrCreateJobFlowOperator that also checks for a dag_run
    configuration to see if we should use an existing cluster before attempting
    to make a new cluster.

    :dag_run.conf emr_cluster_id: A emr cluster id (example: j-2J07A5L8MAU8P) 
        that will be returned as the cluster `JobFlowId` instead of a created
        clusters job flow id.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context: Dict[Any, Any]) -> str:
        """
        """
        breakpoint()
        emr_cluster_id = context["dag_run"].conf.get("emr_cluster_id")
        if emr_cluster_id:
            self.log.info(f"found a dag_run.conf.emr_cluster_id value of {emr_cluster_id}")
            # TODO: Add a check to see if the cluster exists in EMR.
            return emr_cluster_id
        self.log.info(
        f"No value found for found a dag_run.conf.emr_cluster_id.")
        return super().execute(context)
```

That I know works from manually testing in the UI. I'm writing some basic unit tests for these operators

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict, Any

from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_create_job_flow_operator import (
    EmrCreateJobFlowOperator)
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow_operator import (
    EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator)
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.utils.state import State

from plugins.operators.custom_emr_operators import (
    EmrCreateOrUseJobFlowOperator,
    PotentiallyTerminateEmrJobFlowOperator)

DEFAULT_DATE = datetime(2021, 1, 1)

def test_emr_create_or_use_job_flow_no_cluster_id(mocker):
    dag = DAG('test_dag', default_args={'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': DEFAULT_DATE})

    with mocker.patch.object(EmrCreateJobFlowOperator, "execute") as mock_method:
        create_or_use_cluster = EmrCreateOrUseJobFlowOperator(
            task_id="test",
            dag=dag)
        task_instance = TaskInstance(
            task=create_or_use_cluster,
            execution_date=datetime.now())

        create_or_use_cluster.run(ignore_ti_state=True)
        self.assertEqual(task_instance.state, State.SUCCESS)
        mock_method.assert_called_once()

def test_emr_create_or_use_job_flow_provided_cluster_id(mocker):
    pass

def test_terminate_job_flow(mocker):
    pass

def test_no_terminate_job_flow(mocker):
    pass
```

which is based off off the [Airflow Best Practices testing documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/best-practices.html#unit-tests). The issue is that I'm running into an error in my unit tests which I didn't hit in my manual tests

```
    def execute(self, context: Dict[Any, Any]) -> str:
        """
        """
>       emr_cluster_id = context["dag_run"].conf.get("emr_cluster_id")
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'

../../dags/plugins/operators/custom_emr_operators.py:117: AttributeError
```

and when I drop into PDB I can see that the context object is a dictionary and it is missing the `conf` object.

```
> /usr/local/airflow/dags/plugins/operators/custom_emr_operators.py(118)execute()
-> emr_cluster_id = context["dag_run"].conf.get("emr_cluster_id")
(Pdb) context
{'conf': <airflow.configuration.AirflowConfigParser object at 0x7feb476da4d0>, 'dag': <DAG: test_dag>, 'dag_run': None, 'ds': '2021-01-01', 'ds_nodash': '20210101', 'execution_date': DateTime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'inlets': [], 'macros': <module 'airflow.macros' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/macros/__init__.py'>, 'next_ds': '2021-01-02', 'next_ds_nodash': '20210102', 'next_execution_date': DateTime(2021, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'outlets': [], 'params': {}, 'prev_ds': '2020-12-31', 'prev_ds_nodash': '20201231', 'prev_execution_date': DateTime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'prev_execution_date_success': <Proxy at 0x7feb428bb5a0 with factory <function TaskInstance.get_template_context.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7feb428e75f0>>, 'prev_start_date_success': <Proxy at 0x7feb428bb5f0 with factory <function TaskInstance.get_template_context.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7feb42922170>>, 'run_id': None, 'task': <Task(EmrCreateOrUseJobFlowOperator): test>, 'task_instance': <TaskInstance: test_dag.test 2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 [running]>, 'task_instance_key_str': 'test_dag__test__20210101', 'test_mode': False, 'ti': <TaskInstance: test_dag.test 2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 [running]>, 'tomorrow_ds': '2021-01-02', 'tomorrow_ds_nodash': '20210102', 'ts': '2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00', 'ts_nodash': '20210101T000000', 'ts_nodash_with_tz': '20210101T000000+0000', 'var': {'json': None, 'value': None}, 'yesterday_ds': '2020-12-31', 'yesterday_ds_nodash': '20201231'}
```

I know that I can just attach a `conf` attribute in my test setup but if possible I would like to use the same setup methods as airflow to try to limit the amount of mocking I'm doing.

I'm reasonably sure that the `.conf` attribute is [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/taskinstance.html#TaskInstance.executor_config) attribute in the task instance is the value I want but I'm not sure why it's not attached by the `.run` method.